# Android notification isn't showing up

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am attempting to show a small notification in my android app but I cannot visually see anything. `MainActivity` class has a `static field` named `activity` which is is equal to `this`. `message.data` is just pulled from an object. Here is what I am calling:

```
sendNotification(MainActivity.activity.getApplicationContext(), 
                 null, 
                 message.data, 
                 message.data, 
                 1, true, true, true, 0);
```

And here is the meat:

```
public static void sendNotification(Context caller, Class<?> activityToLaunch, String title, String msg, int numberOfEvents,boolean sound, boolean flashLed, boolean vibrate,int iconID) {
    NotificationManager notifier = (NotificationManager) caller.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notify = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Notification",System.currentTimeMillis());

    notify.icon         = iconID;
    notify.tickerText   = title;
    notify.when         = System.currentTimeMillis();
    notify.number       = numberOfEvents;
    notify.flags        |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    if (sound)   notify.defaults    |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    if (vibrate) notify.vibrate     = new long[] {100, 200, 300};
    if (flashLed) {
        notify.flags    |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notify.ledARGB  = Color.CYAN;
        notify.ledOnMS  = 500;
        notify.ledOffMS = 500;
    }

    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1232;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(caller, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notify.setLatestEventInfo(caller, title, msg, contentIntent);
    notifier.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notify);
}
```

I can log messages so I know it is getting called and such- however, I am a beginner to android development and likely am missing a critical part. I am running on an emulator android 2.2. This is all in a plugin object that I have linked to cordova that is running in the background, if that matters at all.

Comment: This may or may not cause the problem or contribute to it or not, but either way: Forget about `static`, it won't work on Android like you think, because the class may not be loaded, `static` or not. The only place where `static` _may_ make sense is `Application`, but even there it won't do what you want it to do when you declare it.

Comment: Hmm, I'll keep this in mind, thanks. After a quick test it doesn't seem to fix or alter program.

Comment: Question is, why do you think you need to store that `Context`. It's important to understand that `Context`s have different lifespans (Application vs Activity) and different meanings. Using an outdated `Context` will mostly not yield the desired result. And using the same method with an `Activity` as a `Context` may produce a different result than using it with an `Application` as a `Context`. Also, there's a discussion here on SO about the difference between `getApplication()` and `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: The point is, your snippets don't provide much of contextual information. ;) The first thing you can try is using `thi` (the `Activity`) for the notification, then you can try the two application related methods, and if that doesn't help, you'll probably have to provide more information regarding _where_ this code resides and _when_ and under which _conditions_ it is supposed to create the notification. -- Haven't checked your code in detail, though; could also be something hidden there in your code.

Comment: Are there any relevamt messages in the logcat? Don't filter the logcat as you might miss something important. Also, the `Intent` that you are passing to the `Notification` doesn't do anything (it has no action and it has no component), so you might try actually setting either the action or the component there to see if that changes the behaviour.

Comment: @ClassStacker I have been trying to use the MainActivity's context for the notification, and it isn't stored. Just the reference to the MainActivity is- unless I misunderstand you? This code is all in a plugin which extends CordovaPlugin, I don't believe that is an activity but just a helper class for interfacing with cordova (which works fine). A thread is running in the background which grabs info every once in a while and if there is a change it populates an ArrayList and sends the data to my sendNotification function which seemingly does nothing :o

Comment: @DavidWasser I have not seen anything in logcat regarding it. With a bit of testing I did uncover something, the MediaPlayer and NotificationService are both being loaded with the sound; I found this out by seeing an issue w/ loading sound but it has no effect when sound is turned off (is had issue loading something). 

notificationIntent.setAction("ACTION_MAIN");
notificationIntent.setComponent(null);

Is what I've added, with no apparent change. Also tried just setting action.

Comment: I haven't used Cordova so I don't know in which `Context` it resides and what it expects. But you call the `sendNotification` method _not_ with the caller's `Context` but with the caller`s Application context, which is not the same. I suggested trying different contexts and can't conclude whether you tried this...

Comment: @ClassStacker Thank you for your help. I have solved the issue and both you and David were correct.

Comment: Great, and thanks for documenting the result for all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new class for the intent:

```
public class StatusNotificationIntent {
    public static Notification buildNotification( Context context, CharSequence tag, CharSequence contentTitle, CharSequence contentText) {
        int icon = R.drawable.notification;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification noti = new Notification(icon, contentTitle, when);
        noti.flags |= flag;

        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent notificationIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("notificationTag", tag);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        noti.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        return noti;
    }
}
```

And I call it using this function

```
public void showNotification( CharSequence tag, CharSequence contentTitle, CharSequence contentText, int flag) {
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);

    Notification noti = StatusNotificationIntent.buildNotification(context, tag, contentTitle, contentText);
    mNotificationManager.notify(tag.hashCode(), noti);
}
```

ClassStacker and David Wasser (In the comments) were correct in stating that a combination of using a correct Intent and correct context would solve this issue.